# transmit strings through ByteBuffer

Tags: java, sockets, bytebuffer

I need to transmit 2 integers and one string through a bytebuffer. And then receive another string through bytebuffer.

There must be something like this:
Read x (int) from keyboard.Enter. Read y (int) from keyboard.Enter. Read the string from keyboard. Enter. All the values go somewhere, are being processed and i must receive the string. All is done through socket channel.

I have done something like this:
SEND

```
Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
int m,n;
String str,result;
System.out.println("x=");
m=scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("y=");
n=scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("String: ");
str=scanner.next();

ByteBuffer bb=ByteBuffer.allocate(100);

bb.putInt(0,m).putInt(8,n).put(str.getBytes()); // problem?

try{

  sc.write(bb);
  bb.clear();
  sc.read(bb);

  CharBuffer cbuf = bb.asCharBuffer();
  result=cbuf.toString();

  System.out.println("Result : "+result);
```

RECEIVE:

```
   ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(100);    
  socketChannel.read(bb);
  int m=bb.getInt(0);
  int n=bb.getInt(8);
  String str=bb.toString().substring(16);

  App app=new App();
  String result=app.longestRepeatingSubstring(str,m,n);
  bb.clear();

  bb.put(result.getBytes());

  socketChannel.write(bb);
  socketChannel.close();
```

but i am receiving a null string...

Or if i put directly bb.toString() i receive something like this: 
java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=237 lim=258 cap=798]

Answer (score 0):

```
bb.putInt(0,m).putInt(8,n).put(str.getBytes()); // problem?
```

yes problem `put(str.getBytes())` relies on the position in the buffer being set previously but because you are using offset putInt functions it will not be.

```
bb.putInt(0,m).putInt(8,n).position(16).put(str.getBytes()).position(0);
```

this line will not work for your client `ByteBuffer.toString()` returns buffer state not contents,

instead of

```
String str=bb.toString().substring(16);
```

you want

```
byte[] b = new byte[length];
bb.position(16);
bb.get(b);
String str=new String(b);
```